# Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS - Headphones HyperX Cloud II detected but microphone is deaf

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, microphone

I updated from ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04.4 LTS On Ubuntu 18.04 all works fine. Currently Headphones works correctly but microphone is deaf. I tried all type of fixes e.g. [HyperX Cloud II mic is not working on Ubuntu 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289350/hyperx-cloud-ii-mic-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-10/1291124#1291124) and nothing helped.

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2109:0811 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0557:2213 ATEN International Co., Ltd CS682 2-Port USB 2.0 DVI KVM Switch
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0557:8021 ATEN International Co., Ltd Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0951:16a4 Kingston Technology HyperX 7.1 Audio
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

pactl list sources

```
Source #14
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_input.usb-Kingston_HyperX_7.1_Audio_00000000-00.analog-stereo
    Description: HyperX 7.1 Audio Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 8
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 816072350 usec, configured 10000 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HyperX 7.1 Audio"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Kingston HyperX 7.1 Audio at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, full speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-Kingston_HyperX_7.1_Audio_00000000-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "0951"
        device.vendor.name = "Kingston Technology"
        device.product.id = "16a4"
        device.product.name = "HyperX 7.1 Audio"
        device.serial = "Kingston_HyperX_7.1_Audio_00000000"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "HyperX 7.1 Audio Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    Ports:
        analog-input-headset-mic: Headset Microphone (priority: 8800)
    Active Port: analog-input-headset-mic
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Comment: Hello. There is no version of Ubuntu 18 or 20 please correct the question and title. You have a link that is to a 20.10 question. Maybe that is your version?

Comment: sorry i am doing this first time. I upgraded Ubuntu from version 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: I upgraded Ubuntu from version 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Corrected